# setState() или свойства класса в React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Здравствуй, путник.
Я новичок в реакте, и читая документацию увидел, что setState() обновляет весь компонент разом, после чего на практике выявил следующее:

Предположим, есть условный реактовский компонент в двух реализациях. Во второй реализации отсутствует state (вернее, он есть, но пустой), и вместо него используется поле класса. В обоих случаях состояние компонента обновляется, и число в блоке div повышается при нажатии на него. Второй вариант выглядит чище и требует меньше затрат времени на написание, плюс удобнее в ориентировании, но есть ведь же загвоздка, да?

Должны ли быть различия в производительности?

Как это отразится на тестируемости?

Есть ли какие-либо специфические моменты, до которых я пока в изучении даже не дошел?

Вариант 1

```
interface IState {
    counter: number;
}

export class ExampleComponent extends React.Component<any, IState> {
    
    //конструктор опустим 

    private increaseCounter(e: React.MouseEvent) {
        this.state = { 
            counter: this.state.counter + 1
        };
    }

    public render() {
        <div onClick={this.increaseCounter}>
            {this.state.counter}
        </div>
    
    }
}
```

Вариант 2

```
export class ExampleComponent extends React.Component<any, {}> {
    
    private counter: number = 0;
    
    private increaseCounter(e: React.MouseEvent) {
        this.counter++;
        this.setState({});
    }

    public render() {
        <div onClick={this.increaseCounter}>
            {this.counter}
        </div>
    
    }
}
```

Comment: С вашего кода ничего не понятно! Можете добавить весь код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменение свойства инстанса класса не вызывает перерисовку компонента самостоятельно. В качестве кейса использования, могу разве что предложить положить туда `Subscription` из библиотеки [RxJS](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subscription)

> Смысл React - создать единый стандарт написания кода фронтенд приложения, а не повысить производительность. Поэтому, для обновление счетчика `counter` используйте именно `setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 })`, иначе выглядит весьма вульгарно

```
import React from 'react';

import { interval } from 'rxjs';

export class TestComponent extends React.Component {

    subscription = null;
    
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        counter: 0,
      };
    };

    componentDidMount = () => {
      this.subscription = interval(1_000).subscribe(() => {
        this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 })
      });
    };

    componentWillUnmount = () => {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    };

    public render = () => {
      <div>
        {this.counter}
      </div>
    };

}
```

**P.S.** На самом деле, *удобнее именно держать всё состояние внутри объекта `state`* в сгруппированном виде, даже если бы можно было использовать свойства класса, проблематично было бы понять, что используется в `render`, а что нет)